# Reformatting list cases of a string/word with its format from another list

Tags: python

The goal of this is to replace all instances of elements from `L1` with their respective elements of of a different format in `L2`.

*For instance:*

```
L1 = ['apple', 'some_fruit', 'BaNaNa', 'ORANGE_123']
L2 = ['The quick brown BANANA jumped over the lazy (APPLE)\n',
      'Then the <orange_123> got SOME_FRUIT\n', 'The End.']

**add code**

output = ''.join(L2)
print(output)

> The quick brown BaNaNa jumped over the lazy (apple)
> Then the <ORANGE_123> got some_fruit
> The End.
```

The goal is for the output to replace all of the instances within `L2` with its similar case in `L1` but **to reformat the case (upper/lower)** for the characters as to fit the format they are in within `L1`.
I know this is not all that straight forward, so if further explanation is needed/ more examples are needed please let me know.

Note: I am trying to convert txt files to a new formatting, and `L1` represents the correct format for specific words that I need to reformat, and `L2` represents all of the lines read by `.readlines` from a txt file.

Comment: I solved this issue by realizing that I could go another way in solving it.

Comment: How about showing what you already tried? "**add code**" doesn't do much here.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import re
L3=[]
for el2 in L2:
    for el1 in L1:
        el2=re.sub(el1, el1, el2, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    L3.append(el2)
```

Outputs:

```py
#L2:
['The quick brown BANANA jumped over the lazy (APPLE)\n', 'Then the <orange_123> got SOME_FRUIT\n', 'The End.']

#L3:
['The quick brown BaNaNa jumped over the lazy (apple)\n', 'Then the <ORANGE_123> got some_fruit\n', 'The End.']
```